# What's the difference between a game tree and a decision tree?

Tags: tree, decision-tree

Straightforward question, not sure what the answer is.

Answer (score 3):

A game tree holds the state of the game after each move made by the player(s).  Its leaf nodes tell you the end result (which player won, or if its a tie).  A decision tree's nodes also tells you the state, and its leaf nodes tell you "YES" or "NO".  A game tree is always a brute-force approach: it will tell you every single possible variation of the game.  In short, game trees are a subset of decision trees.